# How do you apply a predicate while traversing through a fulfilled NSManagedObject?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to apply a predicate while traversing through a to-many relationship using a `NSManagedObject` that has already been fulfilled in a context. I thought about just casting the set as an array and then applying a filter algorithm, but that would trigger a bunch of faults which I don't want as there could possibly be 500+ objects in the set. Is it possible that when accessing this `NSSet` of faults through the `NSManagedObject` that I can apply a predicate or a filter to the set and only fulfill those faults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering the objects in the relationship is correct.  It is ***far*** more efficient then doing a separate fetch.  I have learned this from personal experience with relationship size in the same ballpark (100-2000 entities), and found around a 10 fold speed difference between doing another fetch vs filtering the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering set `objectA.b`, fetch B using a fetch predicate on the inverse relationship

```
NSPredicate(format: "a == %@ AND …", objectA) // to-one
```

or

```
NSPredicate(format: "a CONTAINS %@ AND …", objectA) // to-many
```